# $y^{\prime} = e^{2y+9t}$

Tags: calculus

I think that I have a mistake in my attempt at solving the separable differential equation.

Solve $y^{\prime} = e^{2y+9t}$ if $y(0) = 11$.

**Solution**

The given differential equation is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
e^{-2y} y^{\prime} = e^{9t} ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-\frac{1}{2} \, (e^{-2y})^{\prime} = e^{9t} ,
\end{equation*}
and to
\begin{equation*}
(e^{-2y})^{\prime} = -2e^{9t} .
\end{equation*}
According to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
\begin{equation*}
e^{-2y} = -\frac{2}{9} e^{9t} + C .
\end{equation*}

The expression on the right side is negative for "big enough" values of $t$, but exponential functions are positive. Is the domain for the solution an interval $(-\infty, b)$ for some number $b$? Is $b > 0$? $b$ must be positive to accommodate the initial condition $y(0) = 11$.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: If you add an initial condition, you will find C.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima t'es trop 3afreeta  he's pointing that the left part is always positive and the other part can be  negative

Answer (score 2):

From this equation:
$$e^{-2y}=-\frac{2}{9}e^{9t}+C$$
You can get $y(t)$:
$$y(t)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(-\frac{2}{9}e^{9t}+C\right)$$
W have $y(0)=11$, so
$$11=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(-\frac{2}{9}+C\right)$$
Thus
$$C=e^{-22}+\frac{2}{9}$$
And
$$y(t)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{2}{9}\left(1-e^{9t}\right)+e^{-22}\right)$$

Having solution in that form we can easilly deduce the domain of $y$:
$$\frac{2}{9}\left(1-e^{9t}\right)+e^{-22} >0\\
1-e^{9t}>-\frac{9}{2}e^{-22} \\
e^{9t}<\frac{9}{2}e^{-22}+1\\
t<\frac{1}{9}\ln\left(\frac{9}{2}e^{-22}+1\right)$$
Thus the domain of the solution $y(t)$ is an interval:
$$D=\left(-\infty, \frac{1}{9}\ln\left(\frac{9}{2}e^{-22}+1\right)\right)$$

Comment: I agree that the solution you provided is correct. The domain of the function is $(-\infty, b)$ if $b = \frac{1}{9} (-22 - \ln(2) + \ln(9 + 2e^{22})) \approx 1.395$.  The `stackexchange` member asking the question wants to clarify that the domain of the solution to the differential equation has an upper bound. And this domain contains "very little" positive numbers.

Comment: @Adelyn I've edited my answer to obtain the domain.

Comment: $\frac{1}{9} \, \ln\left(1 + \frac{9}{2} \, e^{-22}\right) \approx 1.39 \cdot 10^{-10}$.

Comment: $0$ is "barely in the domain" in order to have the initial condition $y(0)=11$.